# android XML file not recognized

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I created new android project in eclipse and created `MainActivity.java` and `activity_main.xml` files but the `activity_main.xml` file is not recognizing. **Project-> clean-> clean all project** does nothing . I deleted `import android.R` does nutting. What should i do? see the [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/ee91d785-da02-455d-af01-17174ea81261/e56c00357e4745bc7d1bf1667ff4ef39). [R not generated in gen folder](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/0d0731e0-d0d7-4517-9116-bbe2922e647e/75e7af566cce3e4d91f310be99e2df2a)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Generally in android there are two different `R` files you can acces:

- The `android.R` - provided by the android platform
- Your projects `R` - holding your resources

You have to import your `R` file, not the `android.R`, in order to access your layout. 
This is done using your package name on import like this:

```
import your.package.name.R;
```

The `android.R` is used for resources provided by the android platform, while your `R` file contains the resource you added to the project.

Comment: @ super-qua, i imported project name.R "import com.simbotix.oovoo.R;" does nutting.   http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/5928e229-4408-4893-a092-4e95c8470b8a/48aded3244b7fd61af0c3aea43eb93da

Comment: You have to use the package name defined in your `Manifest` with `package="..."`. From the screenshot it looks like that might be different

Comment: Thanks @ super-qua but package name in my manifest is same package="com.simbotix.oovoo".

Comment: Did you clean the project again? Also, as @gauravgupta stated below, you layout might contain errors.

Comment: I think some error in- R not generated in gen folder https://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/0d0731e0-d0d7-4517-9116-bbe2922e647e/75e7af566cce3e4d91f310be99e2df2a

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it looks like. You should try to fix the layout error.

Comment: I had the same problem;clean the project;  make android studio build gradle again; by restarting IDE ; if it didnt worked just Restart your system; it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean you project and build. it will work. Kindly remove **import android.R;** in your activity

Comment: @ Murali Ganesan, i deleted import android.R and clean and build the project. does nutting.

Answer (score 0):

'R.layout' is not able to find your layout that means 'R' is not pointing to your application resources. It possibly is pointing to `android's` resources because this `R` is of android sub-system.

Look at the import statement, `R` probably will be of `android.R`. So you need to tell that you need your `R` file to use your resources. So you need to `import yourpkg.R`.

If your layout contains some error then your R would be created in build process. So if your R is not getting created. Check your layouts and fix the issue in layout files.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) post may help in getting to know about Why R file is not generated.